# How to add +1 to a div temporarily until it refreshes, and subtract 1 if clicked a second time (etc etc)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addition, subtraction

I have a like function on my site. It takes about 1 to 3 seconds (due to unavoidable sql queries for my site - not the best, but it works) to update the new number.

For example, if someone likes it then they click the thumbs up. The div there then updates with the new number.

If it has 3 likes, then when you like, it will have 4 likes. If you click again, it has 3 likes again. Repeat eternally.

The sole purpose of the javascript is to give instant gratification to users who, if not paying attention, may not be sure if it worked, especially during times when it takes longer than 1 second.

My idea is if I can simply do it with jquery to temporarily display the new number until my site rewrites the div to show the updated number, it will serve this function for what I need quite well.

Here is my idea. Please help me to get it working.

```
var likenum = $(".likenum").val(); // get the number inside the div
var newLikeNum = parseInt(likenum) + 1; // make sure the text is an integer for math functions, then do math and assign to a var
$(".likenum").val(newLikeNum); // refresh div with the new number
```

There are a couple problems.

1. how do I run ONCE, and if clicked again, instead, it MINUS? 
   (moreover, some other issues:
   It needs to keep original likenum for all future functions, instead of getting a new one. This way if my site refreshes the div, the jquery isn't paying attention to it. It knew the original number and now it ieither +1 or -1 to the original num.

So let's take this example for what I want.

```
<div class="likediv">3</div> <!-- original div on page load -->
```

x***click***x (pretend I clicked the thumbup)

```
<div class="likediv">4</div> <!-- updated number -->
```

x***click***x (pretend I clicked the thumbup again)

```
<div class="likediv">3</div> <!-- updated number -->
```

x***click***x (pretend I clicked the thumbup again)

```
<div class="likediv">4</div> <!-- updated number -->
```

x***click***x (pretend I clicked the thumbup again)

```
<div class="likediv">3</div> <!-- updated number -->
```

x***click***x (pretend I clicked the thumbup again)

```
<div class="likediv">4</div> <!-- updated number -->
```

I think you get the point.

So how can I do this? See my starter code above, I think I'm close.

Oh yeah, one more thing. There are many like buttons on the page, not just one. so it would need to store and remember any divs. Because we are liking comments and there are many per page.

For this, only need to use jquery please.

---

**EDIT: UPDATE:**

So, it wasn't working, @VIDesign's answer, but I see why. In fact, here is what the HTML actually looks like. *(Please note I am also including the new working `data-value` as part of @VIDesign's answer)*

```
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
```

Ok so apparently why it didn't work is because when you click, you actually click on `.likediv`, but the `data-value="3"` has to go inside the span which is nested inside the div and can't be touched.

So, how to we fire @VIDesign's answer, except the action is triggered when slicking on the div outside the span, when the `span` is what contains the number and the `data-value`?

I hope this was clear. Sorry for not specifying this originally, I didn't know until now.

So, we need to change this code below to work with above:

```
$(".likediv").click(function(){

    // Use the data-value as the constant to calculate with
    const actualValue = $(this).data("value");
    // Set a max value
    const maxValue = actualValue + 1;
    // Get the value the user sees
    const userValue = parseInt($(this).html());

    // create an empty variable for the new value to display
    let newValue;

    // If the value the user sees is equal to the max value
    if(userValue == maxValue){
        // then subtract one
        newValue = maxValue - 1;
    }else{
        // else add one
        newValue = actualValue + 1;
    }
    // Display the new value to the user
    $(this).html(newValue); 

});
```

Update 2: I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$(".likediv").click(function(){

    // Use the data-value as the constant to calculate with
    const actualValue = $(".dynamic-span").data("value");
    // Set a max value
    const maxValue = actualValue + 1;
    // Get the value the user sees
    const userValue = parseInt($(".dynamic-span").html());

    // create an empty variable for the new value to display
    let newValue;

    // If the value the user sees is equal to the max value
    if(userValue == maxValue){
        // then subtract one
        newValue = maxValue - 1;
    }else{
        // else add one
        newValue = actualValue + 1;
    }
    // Display the new value to the user
    $(".dynamic-span").html(newValue); 

});
```

---

**Note:** The only problem I am having is the ***speed to which it shows to the user in the front end after they clicked***.

I am *not* trying to do any saving to the database and I do *not* want to try to get any value from the database, which would be redundant (cause it already happens successfully in other code in the php in the back end).

This is only a quick hack to update the ***speed at which the number shown is visible***. Please be aware that *when the php code in the back end updates the div* (1 to 3 seconds usually), it will ***override*** anything that is in that div currently.

Also, anything done here should be ***lost on page reload*** by design. It is only a front-end display hack, not an actual updating of any code on the back end.

Comment: How are you getting the beginning value to put in the div?

Comment: IMHO, do this on the backend, update the number with the response from the query.

Comment: @VIDesignz Beginning value is pulled from the mysql database where it is stored. It's the reason it takes a second (or so) to update the number.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath can you elaborate what you meant? It is already updating the response from the php/sql query. It is not fast enough. The jquery I want to do is a workaround to speed it up (well fake speed up but to have that effect of instead update).

Comment: In theory you can set the intial value not only in the div but as a data attribute on the div. Then do your actual calculations off the data value, not the value the user sees.

Comment: perhaps @GrahamPHeath answer is more professional but you could easily do a global varialble setted to false when it loads then clicks set it to the opposite then depnding on that variable increment or decrement

Comment: I'd disable the buttons for the duration and at the end of the 3 seconds the single request comes back with an actual number, then replace their clicks with the number that comes back from the db. I guess that's not gonna answer your question. Sry.

Comment: @VIDesignz If it works can you please tell me how to do what you are proposing (data attribute)? I didn't know about the solution you suggest. I can't imagine in my mind how that will show an instant result. Maybe if I saw it, it would make sense.

Comment: @GrahamPHeath I don't understand you. The initial value shows at page load. The slow is when user clicks to update. What is happening is this: `***click***` then `>>send query to DB` then `>> ok now update DB` then `>> ok code now what is the new result?` << I believe this is what is occurring in human terms and why it is slow. This is why I think that my jQuery idea may work which happens at button click instead of after query, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: make a global variable `var dec = false;` when user clicks then `function onClick(){ if(!dec){increment;} else{decrement;} dec=!dec;}`

Comment: @GrahamPHeath Also I think your solution may not work, because it may result in buggy behavior if you clicked many times in a row when you factor in that the server will update the div also. Like it may say 4 and 3 and 4 and then my server updates 4 and then it says 5 then 4 then 5, yet this is now the wrong num because the real is only 3 or 4.

Comment: @JSmith Without seeing what you are saying in practice I need to see more to understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/n3e5u7bt/34/
Here is an example of using the data attribute. The `data-value` will be loaded from the database and you would end up with this to start.

```
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
<div class="likediv">
    <span class="dynamic-span" data-value="3">3</span>
</div>
```

Then handle the restrictions within the click function of the button/div like so...

```
$(".likediv").on("click", function(){

    const span = $(this).find("span.dynamic-span");
    // Use the data-value as the constant to calculate with
    const actualValue = span.data("value");
    // Set a max value
    const maxValue = actualValue + 1;
    // Get the value the user sees
    const userValue = parseInt(span.html());

    // create an empty variable for the new value to display
    let newValue;

    // If the value the user sees is equal to the max value
    if(userValue == maxValue){
        // then subtract one
        newValue = maxValue - 1;
    }else{
        // else add one
        newValue = actualValue + 1;
    }
    // Display the new value to the user
    span.html(newValue);    

});
```

Comment: yes!! let me see what I can do with this! based on what I saw in the jsfiddle you linked, that is ***exactly*** the functionality I was looking for! :D I hope it works!

Comment: By the way am I supposed to add in the `data-value` into the php/html code? Is it possible to do this by simply cloning the text value inside the div (e.g. 3) and adding the `data-value` into the div using jquery? So that I can avoid doing any modifications to the base code?

Comment: Also will this work when there are multiple like buttons on the same page without updating them all on each click (each needs to be independent)? shouldn't I use some sort of `.each()` function?

Comment: @hblrvce However you create the button/div in the first place, just add the `data-value` attribute at that time and set the value the same way you set the html within the button/div.

Comment: And yes, each button only handles themselves, completely independent.

Comment: let me see if I can reverse engineer this thing to hack that `data-value` in there. edit: yeah I think I can do it. Let me try.

Comment: Check the fiddle again, it doesn't matter how many buttons you have, they all work independently.

Comment: The code does not work, but I updated the code in my question. Oh, by the way I changed on.click to `.click(function(){` which I found to work (although not for this use case which it replaces the whole span inside in that case)

Comment: HAHYAHA I ACTUALLY USED THIS CODE ON STACK ON THIS PAGE (NOT MY ORIGINAL INTENT) FIRST I CREATED A DATA-VALUE ATTRIBUTE OF 0 AND THEN I ADDED 95 HAHAHA NOW I HAVE 95 LIKES ON THIS. XD *anyway*, if you can update to help with my update, that would be great. I'm sure stackoverflow does not want me creating *another* so similar question for this minor update.

Comment: Haha and so I never saw the original even on page load I hid with css which loads first with display: hidden; and then ad the end of the js code I added display block so then it showed my 95 upvote count (or however much I like ;))

Comment: Haha now I have 975 like count ;P

Comment: I changed my answer to accommodate your html layout

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you my friend!! For people who need the original, it is pasted in my question anyway! Accepted! By the way, I would upvote but I need 15 points! Thank you so much my friend! I wanted this answer for over a year! I finally got around to committing to it!

Comment: Fancy a try at a pure CSS solution for fun??!! LOL!! :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231068/what-is-a-pure-css-way-to-add-1-on-clicking-a-div-in-a-page

Comment: Solved! By the way I expanded your code a little. Assuming the div also adds a class called "active" to the outer div when it is already upvoted, then this code will solve that minor bug: `if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) { ... your code here ... } else {  ... your code here ***except change the + to - and change the - to + *** ...`. When you do this if/else, if it is not upvoted yet, then the first function is to -1 downvote it! Else if it is already upvoted, then the first function is to -1 downvote it!

Comment: By the way this has created a huge usability improvement to my site! Now, it is not ***instant*** per se, but instead of 1 to 3 seconds, it updates in about 200 ms - very close to instant and exactly what I needed! Huge improvement! So happy!!! :D

Comment: That's great to hear! Awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

my answer would be to create a global variable `dec` in the scope that tells if you increment or decrement

```
var dec = false;
$("#myButton").click(function(){
  dec = !dec;
});
if(!dec)
 $(".likenum").val(parseInt($(".likenum").val()) + 1);
else
  $(".likenum").val(parseInt($(".likenum").val()) - 1);
```

Comment: Does this work on multiple different elements independently on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

On the road to freedom, living free of jQuery, lies this answer ..

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.likes').forEach(el =>
    el.addEventListener('click', function(){
        let span = this.querySelector('span'),
        now = parseInt(span.innerHTML)

        span.innerHTML = this.dataset.value == now ? ++now : --now
    })
)
```

```html
<div data-value="3" class="likes">
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Love clean and simple. **EDIT**: only thing is this keeps liking. But it is only allowed to like **once**. If you click the same button another time (not a different button), it is supposed to decrease. See functionality of @videsign's jsfiddle in above answer: https://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/n3e5u7bt/24/

Comment: p.s. I like jQuery ;)

Comment: @hblrvce Updated with the needed functionality.

Comment: The problem with this is that when the query succeeds and updates the inner html, then the user can again upvote. You need an initial value as a "standard" to refer to. Though I do like the clean code!

Comment: @VIDesignz True. I think I just read the question title mention *temporarily* and jumped hands-on.

Comment: Haha, I do that all the time!

Comment: I updated the question because I discovered my code structure is you are clicking on a div, but a span inside the div contains the likes number. Can you update this code to do that?

Comment: @hblrvce Updated the code. Also added data-* from VIDesignz's code. Also, since now you're clicking on a div instead of a button, add the necessary styles.

Comment: does this only work if you have an ID for the outer div? What if there's only a class? Which of course it needs class since there are many of the same div on one page.

Comment: cause I don't see how you defined the name of the outer div with class `.likediv` (class not ID)

Comment: You'll have to do [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and run the entire thing in a loop. Or, with jQuery, just replace `likes.addEventListener` with `$('.myClass').on`. Rest of it will work as it is.

Comment: Updated with class, and querySelectorAll. Or do the jQuery thing from my previous comment.